# JNDI in spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, oracle11g, jboss7.x

Can someone please tell me how to configure JNDI name in SPRING MVC? I am using jboss version7.1.1 and DB is oracle 11g. I have defined the JNDI in jBoss server. How to mention the JNDI name in spring-servlet.xml? I have tried many options its not working. I am keep getting Name Not found exception.

Comment: What do you want to do with JNDI? Look up a DataSource?

Comment: @Philippe Marschall yes,

Answer (score 0):

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource"
   jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS"
   expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

Where the value of `jndi-name` matches what you have configured in JBoss. You need to register jee namespace something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">
```

Comment: Thanks for the help . It was the problem with the JBOSS domain.xml. I added the driver class and it works fine.